# How can I tell if any website references a directory in inetpub\wwwroot?

Tags: windows, iis, iis-7.5

I have a server that has hosted many sites over the years... as many as a hundred.  I've got a lot of cruft in \inetpub\wwwroot that has not been well managed.  Say I have a directory called "SomeDirectory".  Is there any easy way to tell if any site in IIS 7.5 is bound to this physical location without going through them one by one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To just see if a site uses the virtual Directory "SomeDirectory" you would use

`appcmd list vdir /app.name: SITENAME / SomeDirectory` (exchanging SITENAME with the name of your site).

However if you want to give a physical directory and get all sites using it you need a more complicated command, piping the output from list vdir to list app to list site:

`appcmd list vdir /physicalPath:C:\inetput\wwwroot\SomeDir /xml | appcmd list app /xml /in | appcmd list site /in` (exchange the physical path according to your needs).

Comment: Great, thanks Broco.  I simplified it a great deal by just doing "appcmd list vdir | findstr MyDirectoryName"

Comment: I should really work on simplifying things... Glad it helped though.